# Bootstrap Set Width for One Tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have an HTML page with a lot of links with tooltips using Bootstrap's tooltip plugin. I have found the following CSS to change the width of the tooltips:

```
.tooltip-inner { max-width: 350px; }
```

Although this works, it changes ALL of my tooltips to this width. What if I want to change just one? I tried this, but it did not work correctly:

```
<style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">    
#my_tooltip .tooltip-inner { max-width: 350px; }
</style>

<a id="my_tooltip" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="tooltip content">This is a tooltip</a>
```

Comment: give the tooltip an extra class then amend your css for that tooltip only

Comment: @AndrewMatthew could you expound on that a little more? I am confused by what you mean. Maybe try making an official reply to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Probably best to do it via jquery. But css will work too:

```
#my_tooltip + .tooltip .tooltip-inner { width: 350px; }
```

and here is the js:

```
$(function () {
$('#my_tooltip').tooltip().on("mouseenter", function () {
    var $this = $(this),
    tooltip = $this.next(".tooltip");
    tooltip.find(".tooltip-inner").css({
        width: "350px",
    });
 });
});
```

Comment: For some reason this code is not working for me, it does not give me any errors or anything in the console though.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uDF4N/38/ Might be to do with where you are putting the js? Have a look at the js fiddle

Comment: try just the css above

Comment: Can I ask why this is downvoted when it clearly works?

Comment: @AlexDavin sometimes you get down vote when you you have few points (117 points in your case). I used your code and it is working so I gave you an up vote.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution worked for me

```
    $(yourselectorname).on('inserted.bs.tooltip', function () {
    $("body div.tooltip-inner").css("max-width", "500px");
    });
```